# Node.js but Webserver expects index.html

Tags: node.js, webserver, web-development-server

For Learning and Testing I generate via node.js on port 3000 dynamically a website.

Want to move it to now to port 443 the webserver (Ubuntu with Cyberpanel) does expect an index.html or index.php obviously - how can I handle this!? When I just modify the port in my node js script to port 443 the webserver also says "already listening on port 443".

Sorry if this is stupid question, I am totally new to this (obviously). Appreciate any hint/tip.

Modified the js to port 443, removed index.html, rebooted the webserver, no effect.

Comment: Please take care when selecting tags for your questions. [tag:web-development-server] does not appear to be relevant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.